# Java- Making a File from template with layout?

Tags: java, file, layout, filereader, bufferedwriter

What I'm trying to achieve is a program that makes a file from the template called WaarschuwingsBriefTemplate.txt (WarningLetterTemplate).The method is called with a Klant (Customer) in its parantheses.

Now when I call this method, it won't write any enters at all, even though there are enters in the Template and I'm trying to add enters in the method itself but it doesnt seem to work. Brief translation of the foreign words:

NAAM = NAME

ADRES = ADDRESS

POSTCODE = ZIP CODE

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FileMaker {
        public FileMaker(){
        }
        public void maakWaarschuwingsBrief(Klant k) throws IOException{
                File file = new File("WaarschuwingsBriefTemplate.txt");
                String newFile = "";

                try{
                        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
                        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                                String line = sc.nextLine();
                                if(line.contains("--NAAM--")){
                                        line = line.replace("--NAAM--", k.getNaam())+"\n";
                                }
                                if(line.contains("--ADRES--")){
                                        line = line.replace("--ADRES--", k.getAdres())+"\n";
                                }
                                if(line.contains("--POSTCODE--")){
                                        line = line.replace("--POSTCODE--", k.getPostcode())+"\n";
                                }
                                newFile += line + "\n";

                        }
                        sc.close();
                }catch(FileNotFoundException  e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                File file2 = new File(k.getNaam().replaceAll("\\s","")+".txt");
                if(!file2.exists()){
                        file2.createNewFile();
                }
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file2.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(newFile);
                bw.close();
        }
}
```

`

Comment: This program seems to be working fine. Hopefully you template file does have multiple lines :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your template is not too big and it's ok to read the file as whole to memory maybe try https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html instead of manual manipulation?

Also use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator-- instead of "\n"

Comment: thanks the System.lineSeparator worked perfectly for me!